# How should I use d3-request ?

Tags: d3.js

I've got a react/d3 project where I'm using `axios.get` to retrieve my data passed into a local url with express. Here is my code :

```
return axios.get("http://localhost:3000/gadata")
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
            isFetching: false,
            data: response.data.rows
      });
    })
```

Instead of axios, I would like to be able to use `d3-request`. How should I refactor my code ?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm trying to find a similar solution.